# Datatables server side: Dropdown filter with all options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, server-side

I have implemented a datatable which operates server sided. However, I also want to make use of the dropdown select filter. The problem I am facing is that the filter shows only the values which are displayed at the current page. As you can see this is not very useful cause I want to have the possibility to filter the table by all data and not only the data which are shown.

I am using Laravel and this package https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables.

You guys have any idea how to change solve this?

This is an example of my table operating server sided. You can see, you only have the shown values as option to filter:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ordering: false,
    searching: false,
    ajax: function(data, callback, settings) {
      var out = [];

      for (var i = data.start, ien = data.start + data.length; i < ien; i++) {
        out.push([i + '-1' , i + '-2', i + '-3', i + '-4', i + '-5']);
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        callback({
          draw: data.draw,
          data: out,
          recordsTotal: 5000,
          recordsFiltered: 5000
        });
      }, 50);
    },
    initComplete: function () {
      this.api().columns().every( function () {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>');
        select.appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )

        select.on( 'click', function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        } );


        select.on( 'change', function () {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );

          column
            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
            .draw();
        } );

        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
          select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
      } );
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" id="example" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid, there's no other way but use another AJAX-call within your `initComplete` callback. That AJAX-call should retrieve all unique values per each column that should be obtained server side and responded to the browser. Bad news, is that `initComplete` is supposed to be triggered upon each AJAX-call for table source data chunk and that may screw app performance.

Comment: But will the table be able to filter something what is not displayed? And isn't it possible to setup something like a hook which online gets executed once the table is inited and not every time again like you described? - Or I just deliver the data when loading the page!